# Self Assosiation array contains additional element

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, model-associations

I don't exactly know how to explain this other than with an example.
I have a Words model which associates to itself. A word can have a variant (i.e. a different version of that word, e.g. `Mouse` and `Mice`).

```
class Word < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :variations, class_name: "Word", foreign_key: "variant_id"
  belongs_to :variant, class_name: "Word"
end
```

Calling `@word.variations` lists all the variations of the base word. e.g. calling this on Mouse would give us an array containing Mice. `@word.variant`, when called on Mice would give Mouse. This works fine however,
In my view I get not only the expected variations but also an extra element `/words`

I am printing with the following code:

```
 <% @word.variations.each do |v| %>
   <%= link_to v.name, v %>,
 <% end %>
```

Printing the variations of `Mouse` would yield `Mice, /word` where `Mice` correctly links to the show page of that word and `/word` links to `localhost:3000/word`

Any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: I don't see a problem with your code... I'd be tempted to look more closely at the form. If it's not too large, can you include all the from in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!
Rather than calling `@word.variations.each` in my view, I had to call `@word.variations.all.each`. I created a new variable in my controller:
`@variations = @word.variations.all`
then in my view I call `.each` on that variable.

```
<% @variations.each do |v| %>
    <%= link_to v.name, v %>,
<% end %>
```

It's a bit nicer that way. For some reason `@word.variations` contains that funny extra element.

If anyone knows why that happens please let me know. Other than that the question is answered.